# How do I make whole table clickable and add color on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table which is collapsible on click of a right angle caret >, so I want the collapse clickable action on the row instead of the angle only.

Secondly, I want the table color to be changed to #E1E2E2 on that same click.

The table is made using Bootstrap classes.

I need some desperate help. Can someone help here, please?

```js
$(document).on("click",".option-tab",function(){
 if($(this).children().hasClass("fa-angle-right")){
  $(this).children().removeClass("fa-angle-right");
        $(this).children().addClass("fa-angle-down"); 
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).children().removeClass("fa-angle-down");
        $(this).children().addClass("fa-angle-right");
    }
});
```

```css
.table td, 
.table th {
    padding-left: 1.75rem;
}

.table-header {
    background-color: #28283e;
    color: #f9f9f9;
}

.accounts-table:hover{ 
   background-color: #fafafa;
}

a.right-angle {
    color: orange;
}
```

```html
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

            
            <table class="table">
              <!-- Table Headings -->
              <thead class="table-header">
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col"></th>
                  <th scope="col">ID</th>
                  <th scope="col">Name</th>
                  <th scope="col">Type</th>
                  <th scope="col">Status <span class="badge badge-danger profile-verification-noti">4</span></th>
                  <th scope="col">Last Login</th>
                  <th scope="col"></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <!-- Table Row 1 -->
                <tr class="accounts-table">
                  <td>
                  <a href="#" class="right-angle option-tab" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#AccountDetails"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                  </td>
                  <td>[0708]</td>
                  <td>Mark Jonas</td>
                  <td>Guest</td>
                  <td class="success">Active</td>
                  <td>22/11/2018</td>
                  <td><a href="#" class="fa-user-imp-text"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
                 <!-- Table Row 1 Collapse -->
                 <tr>
                  <td class="insert-here coll-bg" colspan="8">
                   <div class="collapse" id="AccountDetails">
                  <p>Hello World</p>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>

                <!-- Table Row 2 -->
                <tr class="accounts-table">
                  <td><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></td>
                  <td>[2589]</td>
                  <td>John Smith</td>
                  <td>Guest</td>
                  <td class="danger">Disabled</td>
                  <td>N/A</td>
                  <td><a href="#" class="fa-user-imp-text"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i></a></td>
                </tr> 
                <!-- Table Row 3 -->
                <tr class="solid-rows">
                  <td><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></td>
                  <td>[9147]</td>
                  <td>Murray Loius</td>
                  <td>Guest + Host</td>
                  <td class="warning">Pending Email</td>
                  <td>N/A</td>
                  <td><a href="#" class="fa-user-imp-text"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i></a></td>
                </tr> 
              </tbody><!-- END OF TABLE BODY -->
            </table><!-- END OF TABLE -->
```

Comment: Want to help but do not understand your meaning here: `so I want the collapse clickable action on the complete table instead of the angle only.` I see there are a number of `>` chars, and clicking the yellow `>` collapses the row. What do you want to change?

Comment: *«...  collapse clickable action on the complete table...»* Really? or on the relevant row?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Row is what I meant. Sorry

Comment: Okay! So I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below one of the answers, or edit your question to clarify what else you need help with. Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside any answer). If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer. You won't get any points for doing so, but that will close out the question. *Thanks!*

Comment: Hi Bill - following up again. Could we trouble you to choose a correct answer to close out the question? That would help us out. *Many Thanks*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the collapse clickable action on the complete table instead of the angle only...
>   Secondly, I want the **row** color to be changed to #E1E2E2

Move `data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#AccountDetails"` from the anchor wrapping the angle icon to the `tr`... So the `tr` will toggle the hidden row using Bootstrap built-in feature. No need for additional code to do this.

But, you need some code to toggle the angle between right and down... And change the row color. See the snippet below.

```js
// Whole table click handler
$(document).on("click", ".accounts-table", function(e) {

  // Find this row angle
  var angle = $(this).find(".option-tab i");
  
  // Find all other angles
  var other_angles = $(".option-tab i").not(angle);
  
  // Reset all rows color to white
  $(".accounts-table").css({"background-color":"white"});
  
  // Set the "active" color on this row
  $(this).css({"background-color": (angle.hasClass("fa-angle-right") ? "#E1E2E2" :"white") });
  
  // Reset all other angles to right
  other_angles.removeClass("fa-angle-down").addClass("fa-angle-right");
  
  // Toggle this angle
  angle.toggleClass("fa-angle-right fa-angle-down");

});
```

```css
.table td,
.table th {
  padding: 0 0.5rem 0 1.25rem !important;  /* Changed the padding here */
}

.table-header {
  background-color: #28283e;
  color: #f9f9f9;
}

.accounts-table:hover {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

a.right-angle {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<table class="table">
  <!-- Table Headings -->
  <thead class="table-header">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Type</th>
      <th scope="col">Status <span class="badge badge-danger profile-verification-noti">4</span></th>
      <th scope="col">Last Login</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- Table Row 1 -->
    <tr class="accounts-table" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#AccountDetails1, .collapse.show">
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="right-angle option-tab" ><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a>
      </td>
      <td>[0708]</td>
      <td>Mark Jonas</td>
      <td>Guest</td>
      <td class="success">Active</td>
      <td>22/11/2018</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="fa-user-imp-text"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Table Row 1 Collapse -->
    <tr>
      <td class="insert-here coll-bg" colspan="8">
        <div class="collapse" id="AccountDetails1">
          <p>Hello World</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <!-- Table Row 2 -->
    <tr class="accounts-table" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#AccountDetails2, .collapse.show">
      <td><a href="#" class="right-angle option-tab" ><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a></td>
      <td>[2589]</td>
      <td>John Smith</td>
      <td>Guest</td>
      <td class="danger">Disabled</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="fa-user-imp-text"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Table Row 2 Collapse -->
    <tr>
      <td class="insert-here coll-bg" colspan="8">
        <div class="collapse" id="AccountDetails2">
          <p>Hello World</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    <!-- Table Row 3 -->
    <tr class="accounts-table" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#AccountDetails3, .collapse.show">
      <td><a href="#" class="right-angle option-tab" ><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a></td>
      <td>[9147]</td>
      <td>Murray Loius</td>
      <td>Guest + Host</td>
      <td class="warning">Pending Email</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="fa-user-imp-text"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Table Row 3 Collapse -->
    <tr>
      <td class="insert-here coll-bg" colspan="8">
        <div class="collapse" id="AccountDetails3">
          <p>Hello World</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <!-- END OF TABLE BODY -->
</table>
<!-- END OF TABLE -->
```

---

**EDIT**

I added `.collapse.show` to the `data-target` attributes... So it will toggle (close) any shown collapsible row... That's the trick!

I removed the color toggling... So it leaves the color grey on close.
I also touched the CSS rule regarding the rows padding... It think it's cuter that way... But it only is a suggestion. ;)

Make sure to use unique `id` for the target to toggle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After two or three toggles. Why does the toggle start behaving abnormal like this? http://prntscr.com/mvitjv

Comment: Hemm... Can't tell. It does not happen in my snippet. Did you remove the `data-` from the `a` to move it to the `tr` **or** just copied them?

Comment: Okay. But now after implementing this. I have realized another issue. With this, When I toggle one rows open, but when I click on another row, how do I close this collapse automatically and that row will be active?

Comment: Okay... I will edit my answer to make it work on many rows... And ensuring only one is opened at a time. Hold on.

Comment: The only issue with this now is. When the row is closing automatically because I clicked on another row it's not leaving the row color which we assigned on "onclick" and returning back to the original row color which is white.

Comment: Ho! I taught you wanted the color to toggle... You want it to stay as to mark it as "seen" then... See my latest edit. Note that I touched the row `padding`... For fun.

Comment: So when we click on the row it opens the collapse hence it means that the row is active and to show that the row is active, I needed a color. When we click on another row the second row becomes active now, and the first row will be closed, why show the active color when the row is closed?

Comment: Do you want the color to stay or not?

Comment: On row active yes, on row inactive, no.

Comment: If all other rows are closing in order to have only one row opened at a time... What do you mean with "active row"? -- Ha do you talk about the "active" text in the Status column?

Comment: My interpretation of active row means the row which has collapsed open. Please check these: http://prntscr.com/mvjxk6, http://prntscr.com/mvjy8j, http://prntscr.com/mvjyvg

Comment: Okay... I edited again... I think it's all working correctly now.

Comment: Brilliant. thanks for your help. Just last thing what if I want the padding but no spaces between the rows?

Comment: I meant to say by padding-top and padding-bottom in rows. Here is the screenshot: http://prntscr.com/mvlguh

Comment: I answered the initial question, I think. Now you style it. About the padding syntax, it can be used like this `padding:  top | right | bottom | left` [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding)

Answer (score 0):

<sup>If I understand right</sup> You need to make the arrow action also when the row is clicked ..

- To do this you'll need to create another click handler for the row Then trigger the arrow click ..
- Also to simplify your code you can use `toggleClass()` instead of `add/removeClass`

<sup>**Example**</sup>

```js
$(document).on("click",".option-tab",function(e){  // add (e) for event here
  e.stopPropagation();   //<<<<<<<<<<< add this here 
  $(this).children().toggleClass("fa-angle-down fa-angle-right");
});
$(document).on('click' , 'tr.accounts-table' , function(){
  $(this).find('.option-tab').trigger('click'); // find the arrow then trigger the click .. you can also use `.click()` directly instead of `.trigger('click')`
});
```

```css
.table td, 
.table th {
    padding-left: 1.75rem;
}

.table-header {
    background-color: #28283e;
    color: #f9f9f9;
}

.accounts-table:hover{ 
   background-color: #fafafa;
}
a.right-angle {
    color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

            
            <table class="table">
              <!-- Table Headings -->
              <thead class="table-header">
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col"></th>
                  <th scope="col">ID</th>
                  <th scope="col">Name</th>
                  <th scope="col">Type</th>
                  <th scope="col">Status <span class="badge badge-danger profile-verification-noti">4</span></th>
                  <th scope="col">Last Login</th>
                  <th scope="col"></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <!-- Table Row 1 -->
                <tr class="accounts-table">
                  <td>
                  <a href="#" class="right-angle option-tab" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#AccountDetails"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                  </td>
                  <td>[0708]</td>
                  <td>Mark Jonas</td>
                  <td>Guest</td>
                  <td class="success">Active</td>
                  <td>22/11/2018</td>
                  <td><a href="#" class="fa-user-imp-text"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
                 <!-- Table Row 1 Collapse -->
                 <tr>
                  <td class="insert-here coll-bg" colspan="8">
                   <div class="collapse" id="AccountDetails">
                  <p>Hello World</p>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>

                <!-- Table Row 2 -->
                <tr class="accounts-table">
                  <td><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></td>
                  <td>[2589]</td>
                  <td>John Smith</td>
                  <td>Guest</td>
                  <td class="danger">Disabled</td>
                  <td>N/A</td>
                  <td><a href="#" class="fa-user-imp-text"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i></a></td>
                </tr> 
                <!-- Table Row 3 -->
                <tr class="solid-rows">
                  <td><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></td>
                  <td>[9147]</td>
                  <td>Murray Loius</td>
                  <td>Guest + Host</td>
                  <td class="warning">Pending Email</td>
                  <td>N/A</td>
                  <td><a href="#" class="fa-user-imp-text"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i></a></td>
                </tr> 
              </tbody><!-- END OF TABLE BODY -->
            </table><!-- END OF TABLE -->
```

<sup>**Important Note** while you set a click handler for the all row
You'll need to use `e.stopPropagation()` on each click event on any
element in the row like I mentioned in the comments inside the js code</sup>

> <sup>[**e.stopPropagation()**](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.</sup>

But about **table Color to be changed** You need to specify the exact part to be colored .. table? rows? all `.account-table` rows? all rows except the clicked one? which one?

Answer (score 0):

One simple change will do the trick - but then you will also need a bit of jQuery to animate the icon, since you didn't click on it.

The magic of Bootstrap is that it matches-up the HTML attributes: `data-toggle="collapse"` and `data-target="#AccountDetails"` with the element that has those class/id values.

So, it matches this:

```
data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#AccountDetails"
```

With this:

```
<div class="collapse" id="AccountDetails">
```

**All you need to do is to add `data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#AccountDetails"` to the `<tr>` element that you want to toggle collapse of the #AccountDetails div.**

Since having those attributes on the `<a>` tag that contains the golden chevron is unnecessary now, I removed the attributes from that tag. However, it still works if you leave them there - but they are no longer needed as you can see.

To animate the `>` chevron to/from a down-arrow *when the row (`<TR>`) is clicked*, you can add this bit of jQuery code. *(This is in addition to the code you already have that does the same thing when the golden chevron is clicked)*

```
$(document).on("click","tr",function(){
    let chev = $(this).find('td a i');
    if (chev.length){
        if (chev.hasClass('fa-angle-right')){
            chev.removeClass('fa-angle-right').addClass('fa-angle-down');
        }else{
            chev.removeClass('fa-angle-down').addClass('fa-angle-right');
        }
    }
});
```

```js
$(document).on("click","option-tab",function(){
 if($(this).children().hasClass("fa-angle-right")){
  $(this).children().removeClass("fa-angle-right");
        $(this).children().addClass("fa-angle-down"); 
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).children().removeClass("fa-angle-down");
        $(this).children().addClass("fa-angle-right");
    }
});

$(document).on("click","tr",function(){
  let chev = $(this).find('td a i');
  if (chev.length){
    if (chev.hasClass('fa-angle-right')){
      chev.removeClass('fa-angle-right').addClass('fa-angle-down');
    }else{
      chev.removeClass('fa-angle-down').addClass('fa-angle-right');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.table td, 
.table th {
    padding-left: 1.75rem;
}

.table-header {
    background-color: #28283e;
    color: #f9f9f9;
}

.accounts-table:hover{ 
   background-color: #fafafa;
}

a.right-angle {
    color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

            
            <table class="table">
              <!-- Table Headings -->
              <thead class="table-header">
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col"></th>
                  <th scope="col">ID</th>
                  <th scope="col">Name</th>
                  <th scope="col">Type</th>
                  <th scope="col">Status <span class="badge badge-danger profile-verification-noti">4</span></th>
                  <th scope="col">Last Login</th>
                  <th scope="col"></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <!-- Table Row 1 -->
                <tr class="accounts-table" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#AccountDetails">
                  <td>
                  <a href="#" class="right-angle option-tab"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                  </td>
                  <td>[0708]</td>
                  <td>Mark Jonas</td>
                  <td>Guest</td>
                  <td class="success">Active</td>
                  <td>22/11/2018</td>
                  <td><a href="#" class="fa-user-imp-text"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
                 <!-- Table Row 1 Collapse -->
                 <tr>
                  <td class="insert-here coll-bg" colspan="8">
                   <div class="collapse" id="AccountDetails">
                  <p>Hello World</p>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>

                <!-- Table Row 2 -->
                <tr class="accounts-table">
                  <td><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></td>
                  <td>[2589]</td>
                  <td>John Smith</td>
                  <td>Guest</td>
                  <td class="danger">Disabled</td>
                  <td>N/A</td>
                  <td><a href="#" class="fa-user-imp-text"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i></a></td>
                </tr> 
                <!-- Table Row 3 -->
                <tr class="solid-rows">
                  <td><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></td>
                  <td>[9147]</td>
                  <td>Murray Loius</td>
                  <td>Guest + Host</td>
                  <td class="warning">Pending Email</td>
                  <td>N/A</td>
                  <td><a href="#" class="fa-user-imp-text"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i></a></td>
                </tr> 
              </tbody><!-- END OF TABLE BODY -->
            </table><!-- END OF TABLE -->
```